# Split 1d array into chunks

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to not load my entire tile based map into memory to save RAM client side.  The map will be huge and already is requriring 1GB client side (multi-layered map).

I have gotten some perspective on Game Dev SO.  I am trying to Load zones/chunks of my game map into memory (i.e. 300x300) and then when the player moves 100 steps shift the array and load 100 new tiles depending on direction.  I have tried to work on a scaled version of this and now have a generic question.

---

**I need help when the playerX/Y coordinates are on the perimeter of the map (which causes the chunk to be outside of the map)**

Here is what I have come up with so far (note: player is in center of chunk & chunk always odd number sized)...  It has the following issues(when the character is on the edge of the map):

- change characterX/Y to 0,0 and the bottom left(0,2) coordinate will incorrectly be 7

  > 0, 0, 0
  >
  > 0, 1, 1
  >
  > **7**, 1, 8
- change characterX/Y to 8,8 and the top right(2,0) coordinate of the chunk will incorrectly be 6

  > 1, 1, **6**
  >
  > 1, 1, 0
  >
  > 0, 0, 0

**Here is the SSCCE:**

```
public class MapChunkLoad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short[] groundLayer;
        int mapWidth = 9;
        int mapHeight = 9;
        int chunkWidth = mapWidth / 3; //3
        int chunkHeight = mapHeight / 3; //3
        int characterX = 8;
        int characterY = 8;
        String map = "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, " +
                     "1, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 8, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 1, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, " +
                     "6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1";
        String[] strArr = map.split(", ");
        groundLayer = new short[chunkWidth * chunkHeight];

        //load chunk into groundLayer
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        int count = (characterX - (chunkWidth/2)) + ((characterY - (chunkHeight/2)) * mapWidth); //top left tile within chunk

        for (int y = 0; y < chunkHeight; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < chunkWidth; x++){
                if (count > -1 && count < strArr.length){
                    groundLayer[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(strArr[count]);
                    System.out.println("arrayIndex[" + arrayIndex + "] = " + strArr[count]);
                } else {
                    groundLayer[arrayIndex] = 0;
                    System.out.println("arrayIndex[" + arrayIndex + "] = " + 0);
                }

                arrayIndex++;
                count++;
            }
            count += (mapWidth - chunkWidth);
        }

        System.out.println("");
        //print map grid
        int printcount = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < chunkHeight; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < chunkWidth; x++){
                if (x == chunkWidth - 1){
                    System.out.println(groundLayer[printcount]);
                } else {
                    System.out.print(groundLayer[printcount] + ", ");
                }
                printcount++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Comment: You should probably save people the pain of searching your code and just tell us what you've accomplished and still need help with.

Comment: Sorry thought I was more clear... will edit.  I need help when the playerX/Y coordinates are on the perimeter of the map (which causes the chunk to be outside of the map)

Comment: well you put a lot of effort(maybe too much but that's ok) thus the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but commonly you'd check for bounds inside your nested for-loop that fills the `groundLayer`, rather than checking with a count variable. That way will be much more robust. Something like this:

```
for(int y = 0;y < chunkHeight;y++) {
    for(int x = 0;x < chunkWidth;x++) {
        //Get the absolute position of the cell.
        int cellX = characterX + x - chunkWidth / 2; //Please check if this is correctly lined out.
        int cellY = characterY + y - chunkHeight / 2;
        if(cellX >= 0 && cellX < mapWidth && cellY >= 0 && cellY < mapHeight) { //Within bounds.
            groundLayer[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(strArr[cellX + (cellY * mapWidth)]);
        } else { //Out of bounds, put down a placeholder.
            groundLayer[arrayIndex] = 0;
        }
        arrayIndex++;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this was what you were looking for, and whether it works!

Comment: You sir are a genius (my mind is shot lol) :D  Just make sure to edit this... in case someone else wants to use this for learning. groundLayer[arrayIndex] = Short.parseShort(strArr[cellX + (cellY * mapWidth)]);

Answer (score 2):

So I think your logic for checking if count is outside the bounds is faulty.

I think it needs to be more complex to account for that your array represents a 2D figure. I suspect for chunks larger than 3x3 you're getting a lot more errors that are really tricky to describe. Consider this map where each square's value is its index.

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

when in the top right corner (2) your map should look like this

```
0 0 0
1 2 0
4 5 0
```

but this will fail because count will in some cases be a valid index when calculating xValue*width+yValue, but you want that to be invalid (mapped to 0). Instead you need to keep track of both the X and Y components of count and make your map display a zero when either of those are out of bounds.

```
int countX = characterX - (chunkWidth/2);
int countY = characterY - (chunkHeight/2);
int index = countX + (countY*mapWidth)
```

then later.  Instead of checking:

```
if (count > -1 && count < strArr.length)
```

check:

```
if( countX + x >= mapWidth || countY + y >= mapHeight)
```

EDIT:

As you can imagine this also changes how you count. You will also need a way to break your loop. Something like

```
if(x == chunkWidth && y == chunkWidth) break;
```

I would be more specific, but I'm having trouble loading your original post to use as reference.

I think that fixes everything. Leave a comment if you have any questions. Good luck!